# Newbie Question: simple form not posting data

Tags: html, forms

My form only gives favorite drink data, any help appreciated.  I'm trying to output all the information given in the form.

```html
<form action="https://learn.nucamp.co/show_everything.php" method="post">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" value="name" text="name" />

  <label for="rating">Your Rating:</label> 1 <input type="range" id="rating" value="rating" min="1" max="5" /> 5

  <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
  <input type="text" id="comments" value="comments" text="name" />

  <label>Choose your favorite drink:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="drink" value="coffee" /> Coffee
  <input type="checkbox" name="drink" value="Tea" /> Tea
  <input type="checkbox" name="drink" value="Juice" /> Juice

  <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other inputs than the drink checkboxes are missing a `name=` attribute, so they aren't submitted.

Comment: That is a huge dupe

Comment: Possibly. It was easier to answer OP than to look for a dupe (and the dupe question you've set isn't exactly the same question anyway).

Comment: But the answer is: add name